# ElementRef<any>.nativeElement: any throwing "Unsafe call of an any typed value" error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint

I have the following directive which blocks any alphanumeric characters from being entered into a field.

In the validateFields method, ESLint is throwing the following error message:

> ESLint: Unsafe call of an any typed value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call)

I looked at the type for ElementRef and it has has the following properties:

```
ElementRef<any>.nativeElement: any
```

With this in mind, how can I go about remediating the issue below.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBlockNonAlphanumericCharacters]',
})
export class BlockNonAlphanumericCharactersDirective {
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric = true;

  regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$';

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    return new RegExp(this.regex).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
      // Error thrown here - ESLint: Unsafe member access ['value'] on an any value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)
        this.elementRef.nativeElement['value'] = this.elementRef.nativeElement['value']
          .replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '')
          .replace(/\s/g, '') as string;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the type of `nativeElement`. Since [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) accepts a type (which will be the type of `nativeElement`) the best way to do that is by injecting like this:

```
private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```